# Delete a document from mongodb with _id NaN

Tags: mongodb, express

I am not able to delete a document from MongoDB using **Mongo Express** when it has `_id` equal to `NaN`.
[image]

After pressing BIN button it says:

> Document not found!

Any ideas how to manage it from **Mongo Express**?

Comment: How could you create this?

Comment: Dunno, it's just there and I don't know how to remove it... I think I will have to write a query from the mongo console. It should work.

Comment: try to remove all records if nothing important in that

Comment: db.<collection-name>.remove({}); // to remove all

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the url and dateUpsertFromFile is not empty, I believe that the document do exist in the database. Perhaps incorrect data binding? You can do `db.collection.remove({url: "Vista Room Near BBC Towers...<complete the url>"})` to delete it instead, but my previous point stands. You should be able to find the `_id` somewhere.

Comment: I will have to do it from the app as the db is on the remote. I added you a point as it can help maybe to somebody. I won't accept the answer as I opted for a way how to do it from Mongo Express.